# node.js parse csv file with lazy

Tags: node.js, csv, lazy-evaluation

I have the following node.js code:

```
new lazy(fs.createReadStream('file.csv'))
  .lines
  .forEach(function(line){
    console.log(line.toString());
  });
```

However, I only get the last line of data this way. 
The contents of the csv file are as follows:

> 123,broken
>   12345,stolen
>   1234567,lost

What am I doing wrong here?

I also have this code for the same file:

```
fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
  console.log(lines);
});
```

Which returns the following array:

```
[ '123,broken\r12345,stolen\r1234567,lost' ]
```

Comment: So your file is broken, it should be `\r\n` not just `\r`; which it is as evident by your own test there.

Comment: The library (and your `data.split()`) look for either `\r\n` (carriage return, newline) or `\n` (newline). However your csv file is using `\r` as the line separator. This is incorrect; make whatever is writing your csv file use `\r\n` or `\n`.

Comment: `\r` was the only valid line separator on MacOS before OS X so decent plain text parsing solutions ought to be engineered to deal with it, as annoying as it may be.

Comment: @Chad This was the answer to my question as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`\r\n`, `\n`, and `\r` are all valid line endings, so you need to be prepared to split on all of them.

Convert them all to a common value before doing the split.  Something like:

```
var lines = data.replace(/\r\n?/g, "\n").split("\n");
```